# What is the name of this toy game having seven discs with six stones

Tags: puzzle-identification

I do not remember where I have it from, it might well date from the pre-internet age.

[image: 7 discs, with six arranged like flower petals around a center, each with 6 colored stones along the edges]

I guess the discs can be interchanged and the stones not.

Now, that you got this valuable hint, it is your turn to help in recollecting the name of the game.

Comment: Could it not be a two players game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This puzzle was marketed with the rather boring name, the "Spot Colour Puzzle". Several similar kinds of puzzles have been made, most made from plastic. These puzzles and their solutions are described on [my site](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/circus.htm).

The aim is to put the seven discs together in the frame (one in the middle, the other 6 around it) such that wherever two discs are adjacent, there are two spots of the same colour.

The unique solution for this puzzle is:

> [image: Spot Colout Puzzle solution]

There does not seem to be any system to the colour pattern, and don't think there is any kind of insight that helps to solve the puzzle faster.